# How to specify what Amazon Product API returns

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-product-api

I need my application to be fast so I want to specify exactly what I want in the response rather than having tons of superfluous information in there. I know about [ResponseGroups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_ResponseGroupsList.html) but there isn't a group which limits the information I get back. And if you look at [my current implementation](http://dev.spendmycents.com/products) it sends back a ton of information that has little to do with the products I'm looking for. The real problem is that it's just **bulky.**

Is there any way to specify very specific things per product? For example:

- Formatted price
- Name
- Link
- Image
- Description

I don't care about anything else.

**Note:** I'm using [Node-APAC](https://github.com/dmcquay/node-apac) to handle requests to the Amazon Product API. So it converts the response XML into JSON for me.

Here's what I get back (the bulk):

```
{
    ItemSearchResponse: {
        $: {...},
        OperationRequest: [...],
        Items: [
            {
                Request: [...],
                TotalResults: [...],
                TotalPages: [...],
                MoreSearchResultsUrl: [...],
                Item: [
                    {
                        ASIN: [...],
                        DetailPageURL: [...],
                        ItemLinks: [...],
                        SmallImage: [...],
                        MediumImage: [...],
                        LargeImage: [...],
                        ImageSets: [...],
                        ItemAttributes: [...],
                        OfferSummary: [...]
                    },
                    {...},
                    {...},
                    {...},
                    {...}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I would like to get back is:

```
[
  {
    FormattedPrice: 12.99,
    Name: "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy"
    Link: "http://www.amazon.com/Hitchhikers-Guide-Galaxy-Douglas-Adams/dp/0345391802"
    Image: "http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/ciu/eb/05/0663124128a0de9c79891010.L._AA300_.jpg"
    Description: "<Book-Description>"
  },
  {...},
  {...}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to specify exactly what you want. You have to go through the ReponseGroup. In your case, I would suggest you to pass "Small,OfferSummary" for the ResponseGroup value. It should return what you need while keeping the response size reasonable.