# Amazon Product API not respecting ResponseGroups

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to get all products priced between 12.50 and 11.50. I'm using [Node-APAC](https://github.com/dmcquay/node-apac) for my requests to the Amazon Product API. Here's my code for a request:

```
exports.search = function(req, res){

  OperationHelper = require('apac').OperationHelper;

  var opHelper = new OperationHelper({
      awsId: process.env.AMZ_ACCESS_KEY_CODE,
      awsSecret: process.env.AMZ_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
      assocId: process.env.AMZ_ASSOCIATE_ID
  });

  opHelper.execute('ItemSearch', {
      'SearchIndex': 'All',
      'Keywords': ' ',
      'MaximumPrice': 12.50,
      'MinimumPrice': 11.50,
      'ResponseGroup': 'Medium'
  }, function(error, results) {
     res.send(results);
  });
};
```

The response does not limit the results to a [Medium ResponseGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Medium.html). You can see some of the full response [here](http://pastie.org/6479677) (It's huge). Here's the structure:

```
{
    ItemSearchResponse: {
        $: {...},
        OperationRequest: [...],
        Items: [
            {
                Request: [...],
                TotalResults: [...],
                TotalPages: [...],
                MoreSearchResultsUrl: [...],
                Item: [
                    {
                        ASIN: [...],
                        DetailPageURL: [...],
                        ItemLinks: [...],
                        SmallImage: [...],
                        MediumImage: [...],
                        LargeImage: [...],
                        ImageSets: [...],
                        ItemAttributes: [...],
                        OfferSummary: [...]
                    },
                    {...},
                    {...},
                    {...},
                    {...}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It is not returning what the documentation says should be included in the Medium ResponseGroup. It's returning a bunch of other stuff which is unnecessary. Any help is appreciated!

---

Note: It's also returning products that don't fit the price range. These problems may be related. Any tips there would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Amazon Product Advertising doc for the ItemSearch operation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ItemSearch.html), MinimumPrice (resp. MaximumPrice) "specifies the minimum (resp. maximum) price of the items to return. Prices are in terms of the lowest currency denomination, for example, pennies, for example, 3241 represents $32.41.".

So if you change the values for the following two parameters:

```
'MaximumPrice': 12.50,
'MinimumPrice': 11.50,
```

with

```
'MaximumPrice': 1250,
'MinimumPrice': 1150,
```

the price filtering should work. As for the ResponseGroup, I would suggest you to pass "Small,OfferSummary" (as per my answer to your question ["How to specify what Amazon Product API returns"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397263/how-to-specify-what-amazon-product-api-returns)).